How to run the function with my own csv file here?
import numpy as np
X1 = np.random.rand(100, 5)
from notears.linear import notears_linear
W_est = notears_linear(X1, lambda1=0.1, loss_type='l2')

The above codes work. But currently I already have an X1.csv. I upload it to the same folder. But I don't know how to do. If I use
from notears.linear import notears_linear
W_est = notears_linear(X1.csv, lambda1=0.1, loss_type='l2')
print(W_est)

directly, then basically X1.csv is not defined, though I put X1.csv in the same folder of the functions.

You can see my screenshot photo. How to "define" my X1.csv?

you have to wrap the name of the file in quotes, so it should be 'X1.csv' in the function if the X1.csv file is in the same folder as this script

Someone else said you have to wrap the file in quotes, which is false as the function doesn't expect a string, but a numpy array.
You should first load the data from the .csv file using panda:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from notears.linear import notears_linear

# Load the data from the CSV file
# Note the path is '../X1.csv' as it's in the parent directory
data = pd.read_csv('../X1.csv')

Now convert it into a numpy array:
X1 = data.values

Now it's a valid variable to input into the function:
W_est = notears_linear(X1, lambda1=0.1, loss_type='l2')
print(W_est)```


Thank you. It works. In fact, I find I don't need the path. I only use data = pd.read_csv('X1.csv'). I guess it's due to X1.csv is already in the same folder.

The function expects a numpy.ndarry so you cannot just place your csv in there.
You will have to read the csv and turn it into an array.
There are multiple ways of doing this, for example see the accepted answer here: How do I read CSV data into a record array in NumPy?
For more approaches see: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/08/python-tutorial-working-with-csv-file-for-data-science/
or search the web for something like "read csv in python" or "csv to numpy array".
